# Whats the fastest way to perform MANY transfers of files from my Windows 10 PC to my iPhone 13 Pro?

Tags: windows, windows-10, iphone, ios

I need to transfer 1 single file at a time at various different parts of the day every day from my Windows 10 PC to my iPhone 13 Pro. I am creating a sound file and I need to hear how it will sound from a phone speaker. Currently, I render the sound file which takes about 2 minutes, then I upload it to a cloud service, which takes another minute, then I go to my phone and open an app, then download the file, then I finally go to the Files browser and select the location, then I open the file and listen to it. I sometimes have to do this 20-30 times per day, what is a faster way? Thanks,

Comment: I have iTunes installed.   When I plug in my iPhone, but do not start iTunes, I can see the iPhone folders directly and can transfer them directly to PC.  Does that help?

Comment: I'm not that good with Apple's products or ecosystem, but couldn't you stream that ( wirelessly ) onto your phone? I know I can do it with Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed iTunes on your Windows 10 PC, try to use iTunes to help you do that.

1. Connect your iPhone 13 Pro to your Windows 10 computer using a Lightning cable.
2. Launch iTunes on your computer (or download it if you don't have it already).
3. Trust the computer on your iPhone if prompted.
4. In iTunes, click on the device icon that appears in the top-left corner of the iTunes window.
5. Select the type of files you want to transfer, such as music, videos, or photos, from the sidebar on the left.
6. Choose the files you want to transfer, and then click the "Sync" button to initiate the transfer.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if this will be any quicker, but here is how you can transfer directly via a cable or WiFi.

---

Transfer files between your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch and your computer

1. Connect your device to your computer.

   You can connect your device using a USB or USB-C cable or a Wi-Fi connection. To turn on Wi-Fi syncing, see Sync iTunes content on PC with devices on Wi-Fi.
2. In the iTunes app  on your PC, click the Device button near the top left of the iTunes window.The Device button selected near the top of the iTunes window.
3. Click File Sharing.
4. In the list on the left, select the app on your device that you want to transfer a file to or from.

   For information about supported apps, see the documentation for your apps.
5. Do one of the following:

   - Transfer a file from your computer to your device: Click Add, select the file you want to transfer, then click Add.
   - Transfer a file from your device to your computer: Select the file you want to transfer in the list on the right, click “Save to,” select where you want to save the file, then click Save To.

The file is transferred to your device or saved in the location you specified on your computer.

On your device, the file can be opened in the app you selected in step 4.

---

source: https://support.apple.com/guide/itunes/transfer-files-itns32636/windows

Comment: While this answer is cited it is not quoted properly.